# Is there a better way to store a list of integers in a MySQL Model?

Tags: django, django-mysql

I'd like to store a list of integers in a MySQL field.

My current workaround:

```
import datetime
from django.db import models

class myModel(models.Model):
    testList = models.CharField()

    def set_testList(self,data):
        self.testList = ','.join(map(str, data))

    def get_testList(self):
        return list(map(int, self.testField.split(',')))
```

This works fine as long as I go through set_testList and get_testList to set and retrieve the field.

This get particularly annoying as I have 4-5 such fields in some models, and having to set and retrieve every field through their own set and get methods makes the code much less readable and increases db queries.

Is it possible to create a solution where I wouldn't have to go through custom methods to achieve this?

The optimal case would be to set the field using: `myModel.objects.create(testField=[1,2,3,4])`; and retrieve it using `myModelobjects.get(pk=1).values()` and have the conversion occur 'behind the scenes'.

Is something like this possible (without having to migrate to PostgreSQL)?

Comment: You can subclass the `CharField` to do the wrapping for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own Django model field, like:

```
# app/fields.py

from django.db import models

class IntegerListField(models.CharField):

    description = 'list of integers'

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        if value is None:
            return None
        return list(map(int, value.split(',')))

    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, list):
            return value
        if value is None:
            return None
        return list(map(int, value.split(',')))

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return None
        return ','.join(map(str, value))
```

Then you can use that field in your model:

```
# app/models.py

import datetime
from django.db import models
from app.fields import IntegerListField

class myModel(models.Model):
    testList = IntegerListField(max_length=255)
```

So now Django will automatically wrap the list of integers between the Python world, and the database world.

The above is of course a raw sketch. You probably should read the [documentation on *Writing custom model fields*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/).

So "under the hood" at the database side, we still use a `VARCHAR` or whatever `CharField` is using here. We just have added some extra logic here, that automatically converts values in the database to a list of integers, and it will wrap these to strings before storing these in the database. We thus did *not* construct a new database type. I think however it is more convenient that you can use a list of integers on your model.

Answer (score 2):

While Willem's answer is great and perfectly correct from a purely technical POV, I wish to add that the question itself suggests a possible database design issue.

You are using a relational database, not a mere bit bucket, and relational modeling rules state that fields should be atomic (one field should only store one single atomic value), which is not the case anymore with this solution.

Theoretically, the right design would be a distinct table (model) holding the value, with a foreign key on the "master" model. One of the benefits here is that you can query the master model on the related one values...

Now I know from experience that it's just plain overkill (and useless overhead) for some use cases (if you never need to query on those values for example), and you didn't provide any context for your question so it's impossible to tell whether denormalizing is a sensible design here or not, but I thought this little reminder could be useful (for you, but also for future readers).

**PS:** also, more and more rdbms are building (more or less complete and performant...) support for json  fields nowadays so you might want to check this solution too (eventually wrapping the JSON field in a custom one to make sure you only ever get integers lists).